# Spring inject list of generic interface implementations in kotlin

Tags: spring, generics, dependency-injection, kotlin

Disclaimer: New to Kotlin, may be a easy to solve issue or misunderstood basics.

I am trying to inject a List of a specific interface's Spring implementations, in a regular java class this have been easy like this:

```
@Autowired
List<IMyClass> myClassList;
```

But in Kotlin doing the following gives me a error

```
@Autowired
lateinit private var myClassList: List<IMyClass<Any>>

// No beans of '? extends IMyClass<Object>' or 'List<? extends IMyClass<Object>>' types found
```

Doing it like this:

```
@Autowired
lateinit private var myClassList: List<IMyClass<*>>
```

Makes the injection work but doesn't allow me to use a function defined in the interface that takes a generic object as input

```
// Out-projected type 'IMyClass<*>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun myFunction(obj: T!): T! defined in com.path.IMyClass'
```

So how am I supposed to solve this? Is it easier to rewrite the interface in Kotlin with some specific syntac?

Comment: This java version isn’t type safe since you simply omitted the type information. I’d be interested what the List bean looks like?

Comment: @s1m0nw1I'm replacing annotated values, the interface in the list just has a function that takes T, looks at it and returns a different T value.

Comment: Can you add the definition of the `IMyClass` interface? not the methods, the header.

Comment: @ESala you mean like this?
    interface IMyClass<T extends Object> {

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thing you're doing in Java is just using implicit wildcard. So you have 2 ways here:

1. Try to refactor API and inject list of `List<IMyClass<? extends SomeInterface>>`
2. Use injected `List<IMyClass<*>>` but cast it explicitly to thing you need, i.e. `myClassList as List<IMyClass<Any>>`

Thing here is kotlin's erasure is more explicit. If you don't know what type is there — we can't guarantee your code will work, because there is such type in kotlin as `Nothing`, instance of which can't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation and as answered by `asm0dey`, casting was solution which I felt was better for me, but doing it in a cleaner way was a concern.

Just answering below how exactly I did it in the best possible way that I could think of:

```
@Service
class MyService(_myClassList: List<IMyClass<out Any>>) {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    val myClassList: List<IMyClass<Any>> = _myClassList.map { it as IMyClass<Any> }

    // ...
}
```