# Spring Boot (Kotlin) Autowire failure for generic bean with List<X>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have this bean defined in a Batch application:

```
@Service("updating-processor")
class UpdatingProcessor(val searchService: searchService, val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) : ItemProcessor<SomeItem, List<OtherObject>>
```

I know that the above bean gets created in the app, I put a breakpoint in the init method and it stops when I debug the app.

I have this class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableRetry(proxyTargetClass=true)
class EtlApplication() : CommandLineRunner {
    companion object {
        val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EtlApplication::class.java.name)
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("updating-processor")
    lateinit var updatingProcessor: ItemProcessor<SomeItem, List<OtherObject>>
}
```

> > ---
> >
> > APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> >
> > ---
> >
> > Description:
> >
> > Field updatingProcessor in ... required a bean of type >> 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor' that could not be found.
> >
> > Action:
> >
> > Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor' in your configuration.

I get an error saying that the "updating-processor" cannot be autowired, and it's due to the `List<OtherObject>` as the second type.  If I change `List<OtherObject>` to just `OtherObject` for the second generic parameter, the autowiring works.

How do I make it work with the list?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to this post -> [spring-inject-list-of-generic-interface-implementations-in-kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320519/spring-inject-list-of-generic-interface-implementations-in-kotlin)

You should be able to take the **Action** suggested by Spring:

> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor' in your configuration.

For example:

```
@Configuration
class UpdatingProcessorConfig {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var searchService: SearchService
    @Autowired
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    @Bean
    fun updatingProcessor(): ItemProcessor<SomeItem, List<OtherObject>> = UpdatingProcessor(searchService, objectMapper)
}

class UpdatingProcessor(val searchService: SearchService, val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) :
        ItemProcessor<SomeItem, List<OtherObject>> {
    override fun process(p0: SomeItem): List<OtherObject>? {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: My `@Service` annotation does exactly what the `@Bean` annotation does in your code.

Comment: @mikeb did you try it? It does work, while the `@Service` annotation does not.

Comment: Another option is to `@Autowire` the implementation (`@Autowire lateinit var updatingProcessor UpdatingProcessor`), which probably isn't the best.